# Download a file using HttpClient in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, observable, angular-http, ionic-native, angular-httpclient

I need to download a file from server. I previously used FileTransfer plugin of Ionic and it worked fine. I can also get the download progress with size.

```
    this.fileTransfer.download(url, savePath, false, options).then((entry) => {
        console.log("download completed => "+ entry)

        }, (error) => {

            console.log("File download error => "+JSON.stringify(error))
   });
```

But I need to capture ResponseHeader which I couldn't using this. Moreover, this FileTranser is deprecated now.

So I moved to Native Http ( `@ionic-native/http` ). With `downloadFile` function, I can download the file but couldn't get the response header as well as progress of download.

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
```

And inside the download function,

```
this.nHttp.downloadFile(url, {}, "", savePath)
     .then(x => {
          console.log("download completed => "+ x)

      }
  }, (error) => {

   console.log("File download error => + JSON.stringify(error))
});
```

Then I tried to use HttpEvents using Angular http. This approach has event to get the Response header but tt is causing CORS issue. Have no idea why it is causing CORS issue since the other two approach can download the file.

```
const req = new HttpRequest('GET', Url, {
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events',
            headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Length')
            .set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length')
                //responseType: "blob"//blob type pls
            });

        //all possible events
        this.http.request(req).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            switch (event.type) {
                case HttpEventType.Sent:
                    console.log('Request sent!');
                    break;
                case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
                    console.log('Response header received!');
                    break;
                case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
                    //i use a gloal progress variable to save progress in percent
                    //this.progress = Math.trunc(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                    //Math.trunc(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                    break;
                case HttpEventType.Response:
                    //do whatever you have to do with the file using event.body
                    console.log(' Done!', event.body);
                    //i'm gonna write the file in my case
                    this.file.writeFile(aPath, aName, event.body, {replace: true}).then( (file) =>{

                            function onFileImageSuccess(){
                                //in case of file success
                                console.log("file download success");
                            }
                            function onFileImageError(error) {
                                //in case of Filesaver fail
                                console.log("File download failed  "+error);
                            }
                     }).catch(
                     (err) => {
                         //in case of file.writefile fail
                         console.log("File download Error  "+err);
                     });
            }
        });
```

I also used angular Http Get to download file as given in [angular-request-file](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data). It neither ends in success (promise) nor in error / catch block.

```
return this.http.get(attachmentName, {responseType: 'text'})
   .pipe(
     tap( // Log the result or error
        data => {
           console.log("File downloaded ~~~~  "+data);
         },
         error => {
            console.log("Error in download ~~~~~  "+error);
         }
     )
   ).catch((err: any, caught: Observable<any>):ObservableInput<{}> => {
       return Observable.throw(err.statusText);
   })
```

The answer for the question which I am looking for is,How to get a File downloaded with  Response header and also the  download progress. Thanks.